# Set field as out of focus in extjs

Tags: extjs, focus, mouse

Even though the field is read-only, when we click on the field the cursor is visible and focus is on that field. Is there any way to set the field as out of focus(except to disable).

Answer (score 0):

If this is not for a combobox that has a `forceSelection: true` config, this could be a bad idea but doable as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918264/1062992). Otherwise you could do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11764596/1062992).