# Remove typing cursor from combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, listener, text-cursor

I am using an ExtJS combobox. There is a typing cursor when focusing on the combobox. I tried to implement `editable: false` when creating the combobox, but it helped only for chrome.

Also tried `clearListeners()` function to see if this works on that cursor - didn't help, it still appears in FireFox and IE.

The other idea is to set `disabled` on the input field in combobox. When I did it manually, it helped.

But when I wrote the next

`Ext.get('bu-encodingcount-combobox').select('input').set({disabled:'disabled'});`

it didn't help - don't know, maybe the expression is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you see a cursor is because the combobox gets the focus, so the easiest way to handle this is to move the focus onto the drop down picker whenever the combo gets the focus.

Simply add this `onFocus` config to your combobox configuration:

```
// example combobox config
xtype: 'combo',
allowBlank: false,
forceSelection: true,
valueField:'id',
displayField:'name',
store: myStore,

// add this "onFocus" config
onFocus: function() {
    var me = this;

    if (!me.isExpanded) {
        me.expand()
    }
    me.getPicker().focus();
},
```

Also, I would only recommend doing this if this is a `forceSelection: true` combobox. It will ruin a users ability to type anything into the field.

Comment: how to make cursor when hover to combo field?

Comment: Also if your store is being loaded on the dropDown click, you can load the store in the focus event as such: myStore.load(); Initially this was my issue, until I realized the store was not loaded yet.. Hope this may help others.

Comment: To force this to work in all browsers in Ext 5 you now have to use me.getPicker().focus(true);

Answer (score 5):

You can add the config,

*editable:false*

Then behaves as the normal Combo .

Comment: Unfortunately there is a known issue that this only works on chrome, which is what this is trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

**For IE**

```
combo.inputEl.set({disabled:'disabled'});
```

**For Firefox** -

```
combo.inputWrap.set({disabled:'disabled'});
```

**For Chrome** -

```
combo.inputCell.set({disabled:'disabled'});
```