# Disable input in combobox ext js

Tags: extjs, combobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove typing cursor from combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758035/remove-typing-cursor-from-combobox)

To remove typing cursor from combobox I need to disable the input, wich is a part of combobox and shown all the time. The problem is I tried different ways and expressions and didn't achieved the goal. 
Please can somebody help with my issue?

Combobox id is bu-encodingcount-combobox. The needed input is in bu-encodingcount-combobox>bu-encodingcount-combobox-bodyEl>input
I tried the next expression

```
var some = Ext.query('#bu-encodingcount-combobox-bodyEl > input');
Ext.get(some).set({disabled:'disabled'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see a cursor is because the combobox gets the focus, so the easiest way to handle this is to move the focus onto the drop down picker whenever the combo gets the focus.

Simply add this `onFocus` config to your combobox configuration:

```
// example combobox config
xtype: 'combo',
allowBlank: false,
forceSelection: true,
valueField:'id',
displayField:'name',
store: myStore,

// add this "onFocus" config
onFocus: function() {
    var me = this;

    if (!me.isExpanded) {
        me.expand()
    }
    me.getPicker().focus();
},
```

Also, I would only recommend doing this if this is a `forceSelection: true` combobox. It will ruin a users ability to type anything into the field.

Comment: Genious!! It works! Thank you soooo much! Suffering so long, you saved me, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunetely, doesn't work for IE9, why could this be?

Comment: My mistake, it appears only for second.